# JAVA EE Installation for netbeans and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, installation, netbeans-8

I installed netbeans with JAVA EE but i want to use this JAVA EE version with eclipse instead of installing another version for eclipse only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Apache Tomcat (Servlet Container) or Apache Tomee (JEE support) and then configure Eclipse or Netbeans with them.

Comment: using an external glassfish or Tomcat will work correctly , what if i want to use the internal servers of netbeans with eclipse ?

Comment: Which internal server you are using? Netbeans JEE installer comes with Open Source Glassfish and Tomcat. You can configure any of them in Eclipse by configuring it through Windows --> Preferences --> Runtime Environment.

Comment: got it , thank you @Fahad